# Storyboard won't let me select items in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

So I have a project that I have been working on for 9 months. I have 30 view controllers in the storyboard.  Each `UIViewController` in storyboard has a navigationBar on top and in this bar I have a `UIButton` as the title so that its clickable. I also have a cancel button (Button Bar Item) on each view. Everything is working fine, meaning I can click the `UIButton` used as a  title and change the text at will. I can also change the text of the ButtonBarItem (aka cancel button).

So today I decide I need another `UIViewController` so in storyboard I copy and paste an existing one. Now I go to click the `UIButton` title and it will not let me select it. It keeps selecting the top level `UIView` no matter how many times I click?

So I decide I will go to the view navigator and click on the title button there. So that works fine. But, when I run my app only the title `UIButton` shows up not the Cancel button. And yes they are all linked correctly through cntrl dragging.

Anyone have a clue?

Now if I create a new `UIViewController` from scratch by dragging one on the screen and then I set the top navbar to a translucent bar then drag a `UIButton` to the navigation bar and let go to make it a title, storyboards puts it in the main level view. It will not let me put anything in the navigation bar?

Is this something new in Xcode 5?

Comment: In my experience, copy & pasting stuff on the storyboard tends to be more of a pain than it's worth because you run into stuff like this for whatever reason.

Comment: I tried starting from scratch and the same thing happens. It will only ever let me select the main UIView?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your storyboard? (Including the view structure menu to left.)  If we could see that, then we could probably be of more help.  I've had similar issues that were caused by copying and pasting a viewController.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figure out a work around. What I had to do is either create it manually or copy it, but in order to gain access to the navbar title button and custom cancel button, which I dragged in, is to delete the main UIView.

Its like the main `UIView` is blocking me from clicking the navbar.  I then cntrl drag all the appropriate navbar buttons to the code view. Then add a UIView back.

And no I cannot rearrange the stacking order of the View and Navbar in the storyboard list view (aka left hand list view). It won't let me drag the `UIView` under the `NavBarItem`